# Mapping a single JSON object to three different JAVA classes?

Tags: java, json

Can any one help me out in this , i'm new to JSON . The problem is that i want to map a single json objects Keys values pair to three different java classes?

```
{"firstName":"Sasi","lastName":"Dunston","jobTitle":"Trainee","dateOfBirth":"13/09/1990","bloodGroup":"O+ve",

             "listOfEmail":["dunston08@gmail.com","charles.gmail.com","ravi.gmail.com"],
             "listOfURL":["www.google.com","www.gmail.com","www.facebook.com"],
             "listOfFaxNo":[8888888888,1111111111,2222222222,3333333333],
             "listOfOfficeNo":[9999999999,8888888888,7777777777,6666666666],
             "listOfAddress":[{"streetName":"xxxxx","city":"yyyyy","zipCode":"5555555","state":"hhhhhhh"},                        
                              {"streetName":"xxxxx","city":"yyyyy","zipCode":"5555555","state":"hhhhhhh"}]

}
```

this is my json object i want to map it to three different classes

```
Class PersonDetail
{
         firstName 
         lastName
         jobTitle
         dateOfBirth
         bloodGroup
/* Getter Setter */ of the above attributes
}
class PersonContact extends PersonDetail
{
    ArrayList<String> listOfEmail=new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> listOfURL=new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> listOfFaxNo=new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> listOfPhoneNo=new ArrayList<String>();
    /* Getter Setter */ of the above attributes
}
class Address extends PersonContact
{
    String streetName;
    String city;
    String zipcode;
    String state;
/* Getter Setter */ of the above attributes
}
```

Comment: Thing is that ya i've declared my properties as protected only.  But i don't know how to map it to three different classes

Comment: Create the three objects, read the JSON, assign values from the JSON to the objects.  It would be done in less time than it takes to write your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not tested, but the you should be able to map your json to `PersonContact` using the following class definitions:

```
Class PersonDetail
{
    protected String firstName;
    protected String  lastName;
    protected String  jobTitle;
    protected String  dateOfBirth;
    protected String  bloodGroup;
    /* Getter Setter */ of the above attributes
}
class PersonContact extends PersonDetail
{
    private ArrayList<String> listOfEmail;
    private ArrayList<String> listOfURL;
    private ArrayList<String> listOfFaxNo;
    private ArrayList<String> listOfOfficeNo;
    private List<Address> listOfAddress;
    /* Getter Setter */ of the above attributes
}
class Address 
{
    private String streetName;
    private String city;
    private String zipcode;
    private String state;
    /* Getter Setter */ of the above attributes
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind

The tutorial should enable you to map the same source to different java objects (classes)